# Can git hooks be used on a custom web app setup?

Tags: git, githooks

I often clone some basic barebones applications to start new web projects.
But I often have to edit the same files each time that happen and that's really time consuming.

I'm not even sure if this option makes sense, or if there's something better but:

Is there any proper use of git hooks that may run immediately after clone, that may allow us to, somehow, edit those files, by given (or finding) certain parameters?

Or are we trying to use the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a project, it fetches the repo along with `.git` directory in which the hooks reside, right? So I think you're spot on with the last sentence -

> trying to use the wrong tool for the job

Per [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) there are quite a few hooks, but I don't see any that would be easier than running an external script.

I am but a beginner though, so take my advice with a grain of salt :)